# How to set namespace in XML when also turning elements to attributes using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2020-08-28T20:55:05">
    <BISTA>
        <ID>6</ID>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </BISTA>
</dataroot>
```

I need to delete the 'dataroot' element, make the 'version' element an attribute and define a custom namespace for 'BISTA'. In the end it should look like this:

```
<BISTA xmlns="http://www.test.com" version="1.0">
    <ID>6</ID>
</BISTA>
```

The XSLT I am using is to achieve this is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- template for the document element (omit root) --> 
    <xsl:template match="/*">   
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" /> 
    </xsl:template>   

    <!-- identity template --> 
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">   
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- elements of root to attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="BISTA">
       <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://www.test.com">
            <xsl:for-each select="version">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name(.)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- delete version element -->
    <xsl:template match="BISTA/version"/>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I get from this is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <BISTA xmlns="http://www.test.com" version="1.0">
        <ID xmlns="" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">6</ID>
        
    </BISTA>
```

Issues with this:

- the indentation looks off
- there is an empty namespace in 'ID'
- the unwanted xmlns:od attribute

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve the desired output?

Comment: I am new to XSLT and XML namespaces. If the answer to this follows from a classic reference, I happily take reading suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a default namespace on one element like `BISTA` it applies to children and descendants as well; if the shown wanted output is indeed as shown then you not only want to transform `BISTA` to get the new namespace but all its descendant elements as well.

So use an approach like

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="new-namespace" as="xs:string">http://www.test.com</xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="BISTA">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$new-namespace}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, version, node() except version"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="BISTA/version">
      <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$new-namespace}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or make the last `match="*"` `match="BISTA//*"`.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try. Regarding: "if the shown wanted output is indeed as shown". Is there any reason to not want that output?

Comment: @Stefan, it is fine but saying "define a custom namespace for 'BISTA'" with that output means you need to transform each descendant element as well to have the new namespace. In the input the `BISTA` elements and its descendants are in no namespace, in your wanted output as shown they are all in that namespace `http://www.test.com`. Your code transforming a single element to a new namespace but using the identity on the descendants has to lead to `xmlns=""` for the descendants.

Comment: got it. Thank you.